# Extracting skmaps navigation information

Tags: android, navigation, skmaps

I'm building an Android application which is basically a bicycle navigation system using an Arduino. I plan on implementing turn by turn navigation. Whenever the user is within say x meters of a manoeuver, I have to output the number of the turn to be taken in a clockwise manner.

I'm planning to use skmaps (Skobbler SDK) and the attributes `getRouteAngle(float)`, as well as `getAllowedRouteAngles(array of float values). I would proceed to compare these values and return the index of the angle which matches the route angle. This would be sent to the Arduino and displayed on an LCD screen. I wanted to know the feasibility of the project as well as how should I go on implementing this. Specifically, I want to get an idea about extracting  these values and if these values can be extracted and sent to the Arduino in real-time through Bluetooth.

Comment: This scenario is not possible for the moment